# InputFunctionException when using a function to define file inputs

Tags: python, pandas, wildcard, snakemake

Thank you very much for your help on a Snakemake workflow. I have been using functions to define input files for my first Snakemake rule, identifying paired fastq files from a samples dataframe. This works well.

```py
# fastq1 input function definition
def fq1_from_sample(wildcards):
  return samples_df.loc[wildcards.sample, "fastq_1"]

# fastq2 input function definition
def fq2_from_sample(wildcards):
  return samples_df.loc[wildcards.sample, "fastq_2"]

# Define config file. Stores sample names and other things.
configfile: "config/config.yaml"
  
# Define a rule for running the complete pipeline. 
rule all:
  input:
    trim = expand(['results/{batch}/{samp}/trim/{samp}_trim_1.fq.gz'], zip, samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names)
...)
               
# Trim reads for quality. 
rule trim_reads:  
  input: 
    p1=fq1_from_sample,
    p2=fq2_from_sample
  output:     
    trim1=temp('results/{batch}/{sample}/trim/{sample}_trim_1.fq.gz'),
    trim2=temp('results/{batch}/{sample}/trim/{sample}_trim_2.fq.gz')
  log: 
    'results/{batch}/{sample}/trim/{sample}_trim_reads.log'
  shell:
    '{config[scripts_dir]}trim_reads.sh {input.p1} {input.p2} {output.trim1} {output.trim2} &>> {log}'
```

However, when I use the same input function in a new rule, to count the reads in these paired fastq files as here:

```
rule reads_output:
  input:
    p1=fq1_from_sample,
    trim1='results/{batch}/{samp}/trim/{samp}_trim_1.fq.gz',
    kr1='results/{batch}/{samp}/kraken/{samp}_trim_kr_1.fq.gz'
  output:
    reads_stats='results/{batch}/{samp}/stats/{samp}_read_counts.txt'
  log:
    'results/{batch}/{samp}/stats/{samp}_read_counts.log'
  shell:    
    '''
    {config[scripts_dir]}reads_output.sh {input.p1} {input.p2} {input.kr1} {output.reads_stats} &>> {log}
    '''
```

I run into the following error:

```
InputFunctionException in line 91 of /oak/stanford/scg/lab_jandr/walter/tb/mtb_tgen/workflow/Snakefile:
AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'sample'
Wildcards:
batch=MT01_MtB_Baits-2021-09-17
samp=10561-Food
```

I'm wondering if you have any suggestions on how to use the same function to define inputs throughout a Snakemake pipeline?

Thank you again and best!

Answer (score 0):

From the new rule definition, it seems you are using `samp` as the wildcard keyword in rule `reads_output`, while the function expects `sample`. The possible solutions include:

- changing the wildcard definition in the rule `reads_output` (this is the preferred solution as consistent wildcard names improve readability);
- allow functions to accept a second argument that identifies which key in the wildcards to use. The rough idea is below:

  ```py
  def fq1_from_sample(wildcards, argument='sample'):
       condition = wildcards.get(argument)
       return samples_df.loc[condition, "fastq_1"]

  # note that the relevant rule should pass the second argument
  # for example
  #     input: lambda wildcards: fq1_from_sample(wildcards, argument='samp')
  ```
- a more dangerous approach is to redefine the function with a `try`/`except`:

  ```py
  # THIS IS A BAD IDEA, BUT MIGHT BE USEFUL FOR DEBUGGING
  def fq1_from_sample(wildcards):
       try:
           return samples_df.loc[wildcards.sample, "fastq_1"]
       except:
           return samples_df.loc[wildcards.samp, "fastq_1"]
  ```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. As you suggested, I  updated the rule reads_output so that it now uses 'sample' as the wildcard name, not 'samp'. I'm wondering though - should I name the wildcard consistently across all rules? Should I just use 'sample' as the wildcard throughout, which matches the name of the variable expected by the function? Thank you again!

Comment: Consistent wildcard naming is a good practice. It's not necessary though, so if there are good reasons not to use consistent names, you can use a workaround with the second argument.